# Finding all entire functions such that for all $|z| \geq 1$ we have $|f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{|z|}$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I am studying for my complex analysis exam and this question popped up few years ago on the "mini quiz":

> Find all $f \in H(\mathbb{C})$ such that for all $|z| \geq 1$ we have $|f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{|z|}$.

The hint was to use some theorem about entire functions.

Could anyone give me a hand? I have no idea how to tackle this and this seems like one or two liner.

Comment: It seems as though the function $zf(z)$ is bounded on all of $\Bbb C$? Do you know any property about entire bounded functions?

Comment: Entire bounded functions are constant.

Comment: Precisely! So once you verify that $zf(z)$ is bounded on all of $\Bbb C$, what can you conclude then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M$ be the maximum of the restriction of $f$ to $\overline{D_1(0)}$. Then, for each $z\in\Bbb C$, $|f(z)|\leqslant\max\{M,1\}$. Therefore, by Liouville's theorem, $f$ is constant. It now follows from the fact that $\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac1{|z|}=0$ that that constant must be $0$.

Comment: And the constant must be $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I've added that to my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean $|zf(z)| \le \max\{M, 1\}$?

Comment: No. I wrote what I meant. If $|z|\leqslant1$, then $|f(z)|\leqslant M$. And if $|z|\geqslant1$, then $|f(z)|\leqslant\frac1{|z|}\leqslant1$. So, in any case, $|f(z)|\leqslant\{M,1\}$.

Comment: Oh right, my apologies.